# Is there exist a solution to $x^3 = 3x^2(q-p)+3x(q^2-p^2)+(q^3-p^3)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there exist a solution to $$x^3 = 3x^2(q-p)+3x(q^2-p^2)+(q^3-p^3)$$
$$x, p, q \in \mathbb{N} \space\ \land \space\ q > p$$
or not.

I believe the answer is no, but I have not found proof.

PS: This question has no source and I came across it in a different way while solving another question I also checked it with the computer up to $10^4$ for each variable and did not find an answer.

Comment: How have you tried to solve this problem? Alternatively, what is the context of this problem; where did you find it, and what do you know about it?

Comment: $$x^3=-x^3+(x+q)^3+x^3-(x+p)^3$$
Fermat's theorem again?

Comment: Why not re-order terms and use Cubic Equation Formula?

Answer (score 1):

By simple manipulation of the equation you can find the equivalent
$$(x+p)^3+x^3=(x+q)^3$$ which it is quite known to be impossible.

Comment: Is there a direct way for this particular case where I don't use Fermat's theorem? I know that there is a special argument for the case of n=3, but apart from that, according to the original equation, is it not possible to provide a new way?

To be honest, before posting this, I came up with what you wrote by converting the equation. But I didn't mention this in the question because I didn't want to keep our minds closed.